# Why does NMAp find disconnected devices?

Tags: ethernet, arp, ip-link-local

I want to wake up and see the devices connected on my local network, using NMAP.

So I execute this command :

```
sudo nmap -sn -PU[7] -PE 10.11.204.1/24
```

(extract from the man page :

- sn: Ping Scan - disable port scan
- PS/PA/PU/PY[portlist]: TCP SYN/ACK, UDP or SCTP discovery to given ports
- PE/PP/PM: ICMP echo, timestamp, and netmask request discovery probes)

So, NMAP finds perfectly devices. But lets say device A is found, if I disconnect A from the network (airplane mode), and execute the exact same NMAP command : NMAP will continue to find A.
If I keep executing the command, A will be found as online ("Host is up (0.0047s latency).") during some time, and after 2/3 minutes it will not be found anymore by NMAP.
And what is really strange is that I have information about latency overtime even when I have manually disconnected A.

It appears that there is somewhere a timeout, maybe the arp-timeout ?
And one thing I dont understand, even if there is a timeout why does NMAP gives me a latency when A is physically disconnected ?

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you aren't scanning the device you think you are.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am. The fact that the device is removed after 1/2 minutes proves it.

Comment: Have you ever found a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Hm, the same experience here today. For one particular IP address was nmap -sP scan telling 'Host is alive'. Does not matter if the network cable was in or out :( Any idea what's going wrong?
Thanks.